# .htaccess SEO dynamic urls not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, seo

I have a page with a link with a query string that loads another page with the result of the query.

```
a href="news-detail.php?nrf=<?php echo $ntitle; ?>"><?php echo "<img src=newsimgs/thumbs/".$nphoto1.">" ?></a>
```

Now when the new-detail page loads, i get the url as

```
https://www.xyzee.org/news-detail.php?nrf=Testing
```

But i want it to load as

```
https://www.xyzee.org/news-detail/Testing
```

I have looked online for tutorials on mod_rewrite and tried different samples but for reasons beyond my understanding, i cant get it to work.
one of the sample code i have tried is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^news-detail/([A-Za-z0-9-]+) news-detail.php?nrf=$1 [NC]

</IfModule>
```

This should work when i click the link that loads the details page but it dose not. The page still loads with the link as **https://www.xyzee.org/news-detail.php?nrf=Testing**

When i type directly in the browser, https://www.xyzee.org/news-detail/Testing, the page actually loads but the links to the css, js, images, etc, are all broken.
I have tried so many ways to resolve this but cant seem to find a solution.
Is it the link with the query string that is the problem or is it something else, i just don't know.
Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using mod_rewrite doesn't replace the links inside your documents. You have to do this inside your own code:

```
<a href="news-detail/<?php echo $ntitle; ?>"><?php echo "<img src=newsimgs/thumbs/".$nphoto1.">" ?></a>
```

After that, you must also update the paths to your external resources, as the called page is now in a sub-directory. So you could append `../` to all included client side resouces inside the detail page.

To prevent this, the better way would be to use absolute paths or add the `<base />` to the page's header.

Comment: @Phillipp Thanks for your response. It works now. The change in the link structure and the inclusion of `<base href="https://www.xyzee.org/">` made all the difference.  Now its up to me to explore more on this. Thanks.

Comment: Assuming i want a link as `https://www.xyzee.org/news-detail/1/Testing`, how would i rewrite the link structure on my first page? If i have changed my .htaccess to now be `RewriteRule ^news-detail/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) news-detail.php?nrf=$1 [NC]` If I use this `<a href="news-detail/<?php echo $newsID; ?>/<?php echo $ntitle; ?>"><?php echo "<img src=newsimgs/thumbs/".$nphoto1.">" ?></a>` i can't seem to get the value on the response page

Comment: You have to pass the id as well in the rewrite rule using `$2` (for the second matching group) - `news-detail.php?nrf=$1&id=$2`

Comment: Thanks. sorted it out.